# Expand one row at a time in RadGridView Telerik C# WPF

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

I have a telerik RadGridView with a HierarchyChildTemplate to show a child grid when expanded. Now I would like to have only one item expanded at the same time. How should this be done? I can find options for WinForms but not for use in WPF.

I am using the HierarchyChildTemplate to show the grid as explained [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/hierarchical-gridview/how-to/access-child-gridview)

I tried implementing the "RowIsExpandedChanging" event, but don't know exactly what to do from there. I can do:

```
private void RowIsExpandedChanging_EventHandler(RowCancelEventArgs eventArgs)
    {            
        eventArgs.Row.GridViewDataControl.CollapseAllHierarchyItems();            
    }
```

But this will cause a stack overflow because it will recursively call itself.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you expand the items, i.e. why and how are you expanding more than one item at the same time?

Comment: Using the HierarchyChildTemplate as explained here: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/hierarchical-gridview/how-to/access-child-gridview

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you have

```
<telerik:GridViewToggleRowDetailsColumn>
```

As this is functional column for RadGridView, which displays "+" or "-". If so, set it property:

```
ExpandMode="Single"
```